# React Native - Is there a way to implement a scrolling view inside a PanGestureHandler? (Android and iOS)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a cross platform scrollable bottom sheet component with react native similar to ones implemented by Apple (Apple Maps), Yelp (Map Search), etc.

I've tried using react-native reanimated-bottom-sheet which allows the scrolling behavior within the bottom sheet, but the main issue is that the bottom sheet does not properly respond to the velocity of the swipe leading to some sub par UX.

Instead I've built a component using PanGestureHandler as seen below. I'd like to implement a scrollable list within the component. Currently a scrollable view will scroll on iOS. Scrolling does not work at all on android for me.

Furthermore, I'd like the ScrollView to pass the swipe to the PanGestureHandler when the list has reached the top. Currently, on iOS, when there is a ScrollView within the PanGestureHandler, the user must use a handle above the ScrollView to drag/swipe the bottom sheet.

I'm sure there's a way to do it, but I've reached a dead end. Any direction or help is appreciated!

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { PanGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { onGestureEvent, withSpring, clamp } from 'react-native-redash';

const { Value } = Animated;
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;

const BottomSheet = ({ snapTop, snapCenter, snapBottom, renderContent }) => {
    const SNAP_TOP = screenHeight * snapTop;
    const SNAP_BOTTOM = screenHeight * snapBottom;
    const SNAP_CENTER = screenHeight * snapCenter;

    const translationY = new Value(0);
    const velocityY = new Value(0);
    const state = new Value(State.UNDETERMINED);
    const offset = new Value(SNAP_TOP);
    const gestureHandler = onGestureEvent({
        translationY,
        state,
        velocityY
    });

    const springConfig = {
        damping: 20,
        mass: 1,
        stiffness: 150,
        overshootClamping: false,
        restSpeedThreshold: 0.1,
        restDisplacementThreshold: 0.1
    };
    const translateY = clamp(
        withSpring({
            state,
            offset,
            value: translationY,
            velocity: velocityY,
            snapPoints: [SNAP_TOP, SNAP_CENTER, SNAP_BOTTOM],
            config: springConfig
        }),
        SNAP_BOTTOM,
        SNAP_TOP
    );

    return (
        <PanGestureHandler {...gestureHandler}>
            <Animated.View
                style={[
                    styles.bottomSheet,
                    {
                        height: screenHeight,
                        transform: [{ translateY }]
                    }
                ]}
            >
                {renderContent}
            </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bottomSheet: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 1,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        borderTopRightRadius: 12,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 12,
        elevation: 3,
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: -1 },
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    }
});

export default BottomSheet;
```